# Quick device app starting from XCode Run

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode4.5

Old XCodes and new XCode have 1 problem:

A very long time from Run button pushing to app starting on device, if resources of app is biggest.

When we push a Run button, XCode doing this steps:

> 1) Compile a changed classes
>
> 2) Building a app
>
> 3) Copy .app to device with all resources
>
> 4) Sandboxing
>
> 5) App is runned

Example:

If resources size is 1 Gb, then app is running after 1 min or more.

Anybody knows? How to decrease time of app starting OR disable a resource copying at each time?

Answer (score 1):

I founded a one solution of this, but maybe a many people will refute this method.

Yes, this method work not for all projects, but i already want to say for all:

> 1) In XCode we adding our resource folder, 
>          for XCode will detect him and will copy to device;
>
> 2) At first time we must just Run for all resources will copied to device. 
>          Now we have a resources folder in Mac and in Device;
>
> 3) Now i just Replacing resource folder to another temp folder. 
>          And create a Empty folder with same name. Now XCode will see a folder, 
>          and not will say to us, what resource folder is missing;
>
> 4) Changing some code and push a Run. It's great, step 3 with resource copying 
>          is going at Fastest!

If any file is missing in resource folder, XCode will not delete him from device, you can found a many questions here about this. So, this method is work, if you today working Only on code modifing.

If you want work with resources (add, delete, modify), you just Replacing a resource folder back and working =)